# How to search array keys in JavaScript/jQuery using indexOf

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array `members`. This array has a name as the index (e.g. "John Smith") and an array with "degree" and "id", like so:

[image: Array]

I have a search that fires on `keyup` action. It is supposed to search through the member names (the index) and then output the name of any matching members to the console:

```
function memberSearch(){
    var $input = $("#guestsearch>input");
    var val = $input.val();
    console.log(val);

    $.each(members, function(i,v){
        if(i.indexOf(val)>-1){
            console.log(members[i]);
        }
    })
}
```

However, this doesn't output anything except the search value `val`. Even if the `$.each` function is just `console.log(i)`, nothing outputs.

If I manually type `console.log(members)` into console, the screenshot from above is the result.

`members` is populated by this segment of a function:

```
$.each(json.response.data[0].members, function(i,v){
    var m = json.response.data[0].members[i];
    var name = m.name;
    if(name.typeof!=="undefined"&&name!=""&&name!=null&&name.length>0){
        members[name] = [];
        members[name]["degree"] = m.degree;
        members[name]["id"] = m.id;
    }
})
```

How can I make this search work?

Comment: where are you defining members?

Comment: @JordanHendrix Outside of any function - `var members = [];`, then it is populated by another function

Comment: can you log members in the the member search?

Comment: `members` is an Array? Seems like you're describing a plain Object. Where's the code? Are you trying to put non-index names on an Array? If so, `$.each` will ignore them.

Comment: @squint Apologies - I've changed the question. In that case, how can I search the indexes if they are strings (member names) using `indexOf`?

Comment: The solution you chose isn't dealing with the actual problem. Your issue is that you're using an Array instead of an Object. This: `members[name] = [];` should be this: `members[name] = {};`. That's how you store key/value pairs where the key is some arbitrary string value. Then the `$.each` will work.

Comment: Also, I doubt this is doing what you expect: `name.typeof!=="undefined"`. If you were trying to check if `name` is not `undefined`, then just do `name !== undefined`. However, that entire condition is way more verbose than needed, especially since you want to disallow an empty string. You can just do `if (name) {...` or if it could be some other truthy value, then `if (name && typeof name === "string") {...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If members is an object, which it looks like with the key/value pairs, you can use `Object.keys(objVariable)` to get the keys of an object to loop over and do your comparison/regex logic on.

```
Object.keys(members).forEach(function(name){
    if (/* logic to match on name */) {
        console.log(members[name]);
    }
});
```

Otherwise if members is an array containing those objects...

```
var matchingUsers = members.filter(function(){
    var username = Object.keys(this)[0];

    return (/* match username to whatever */);
});
```

Then matchingUsers would be an array containing all the users that passed your criteria.